# A way to observe url in urlbar of firefox, and get an event every time it changes

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I need it for my firefox extension.
I don't care about waiting the page load completely, I want only observe URL and get an event every time it changes, also when I do history back and forward.

**edit:** I saw [An observer for URL changes (Firefox Extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549831/an-observer-for-url-changes-firefox-extension), but i wondering if there is something much simpler, like an event that fires every time the url is part of an action, like page request, history back and forward ecc..

Comment: I think somebody asked the exact some question yesterday and got an answer. You might find it in the list or through the search.

Comment: The helpfully suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549831/an-observer-for-url-changes-firefox-extension is actually mistitled and probably is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners#Example.3a_Notification_when_the_value_in_Address_Bar_changes

Also [How can i check if url of current browser tab is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060779/how-can-i-check-if-url-of-current-browser-tab-is-changed)

Comment: If someone have the same problem, i found another solution, it's more quik and maybe less "professional", but it works: use DOMTitleChanged event. It's fired every time the content of browser change, including history back and forward and new tabs.

Answer (score 0):

[SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/) has a Javascript library that lets you do just that.