# Retrieving HTTP status code from a loaded xul:browser tag

Tags: xul, http-status-codes

Thanks to everyone in advance -

I took a look at this -

[An observer for page loads in a custom xul:browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549831/an-observer-for-page-loads-in-a-custom-xulbrowser)

I am guessing that might be a path for determining the HTTP status code, but does anyone know of an easier way? I have flipped through the contentDocument as well...no dice.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked for a bit and I don't think there is an easier way. The HTTP status code is an attribute of a request (and only of an HTTP request), so it appears to die with the request object (nsIHttpChannel), since nothing cares to save it.

You might be interested in this Firefox project, by the way: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Projects/Network_Error_Pages

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - here is what I ended up using to get the headers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWebProgress